# Do you test on high-res screens and with non-standard/high contrast colour schemes?

Tags: delphi, user-interface, dpi

I use a non-default Windows colour scheme on most of my machines, and have a laptop with a 124 DPI screen, which Windows is set to.

A lot of programs I tested or even use daily seem to have problems with that, showing for example non-standard sizes of controls, cut-off UI elements, unreadable text and so on.  There is the whole range from slightly annoying to (nearly) unusable.

Now I feel that a lot of these issues are unnecessary.  A simple test run on a high-resolution screen in a few colour schemes would show them, some of them are even very easy to correct (like always using clWindow, clWindowText and clBtnFace instead of clWhite, clBlack and clSilver).  Some of them are harder, like proper control sizing.

So my question is: Do you try to follow the recommendations in the UI guidelines regarding system colours, sizing and spacing of UI elements, and font sizes and faces?  Is testing for compliance to them part of your QA process?  Do you even try to lay out your forms in dialog units instead of pixels, even though most of the IDEs (Delphi in my case) have pixel-oriented designers?

[EDIT]: On re-reading this after sleeping I notice that this question may look like an invitation for fruitless discussion.  It is not meant that way, I'd definitely be interested in tools to help me create applications that conform to the UI interface guidelines, an area where I feel Delphi is letting me down a little.  See also my own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely don't. It costs time that I prefer spending on improving the experience of many rather than the few who use non-standard windows settings. A few things I usually do, which should still fix some of these issues:

- use clWindows etc. because that's the standard for Delphi controls anyway, so why change it?
- place labels above entry fields rather than to the left, which should solve many size problems
- make sure the forms resize properly, by setting the anchors
- make sure the tab order is correct (which can become a major annoyance if not done)

But I certainly don't take the time to set up test computers with odd resolutions and colors, or even worse, change my development box to use them (which will screw lots of things that again take time to reset properly).

If a paying customer reports problems with non-standard settings, it depends on the customer whether they will be addressed. If he orders 100 licenses, his chances are good. If he uses these settings because he is visually impaired, his chances are good. If he makes it part of the requirement, I will do it, but charge for the additional work.

Comment: Testing this is easy in VMs on the dev machine.  And while I can somewhat understand your reasoning I find it also a pity, because we are in this situation only because nobody seems to care, including the providers of our dev tools...
I just love the Mac where this is necessary to be successful!

Answer (score 2):

Today, so much software doesn't work properly at a non-standard DPI that I don't think it's worth trying to fix it. The trouble-shooting FAQs for many applications just instruct users to switch to a normal font size for related problems. Microsoft acknowledged lack of proper DPI support in 3rd-party software and redesigned the display scaling methods in Windows Vista, where all GDI operations are scaled on a low level instead of relying on applications being aware of the DPI setting.

Final answer: it depends on your software's audience. If your software is likely to be used by disabled users, it might be worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using the proper colour constants for standard colours I invest some extra effort for applications that we need to use internally on high DPI screens, or where customers may need this.

I have a unit with helper functions for determining proper sizes and placement margins, which compute these from the default GUI font and the standard values in dialog units as given in the UI guidelines, and with helper functions to compute the maximum width / height of an array of controls, place controls, things like that.  For fixed size forms and dialogs I calculate the placement of controls once after translating their text with GNU gettext, for resizable forms I do this in an OnResize handler.

This gives good results, is however time-consuming.  I would like to have something like the [wxWidgets sizer functionality](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_sizeroverview.html#sizeroverview), which automates resizing once the minimum size of a control is set.  I have never seen something similar for Delphi, though.

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally test it myself for large fonts, because my Vista laptop is set to Large Fonts. Colors, not so much, but I rarely specify colors on controls.

However, proper resizing is pretty hard. I usually set Forms scale to false, so as that they won't resize wrong.

There are a few tools for auto-resizing forms. I did look into them, but never got around to testing them properly:

- [TFormResizer](http://www.delphi32.com/vcl/1289/download,xid,1289.asp)
- [ElasticForm](http://www.elasticform.com/)  - ironically (given the component's area) most of the text in this page won't show up in Chrome...
- JVAutoFormSize (in JVCL - doesn't seem to be very useful from what I read)

Comment: I did look into your provided links, but nothing works for me :-(